# Why, in a certificate, TBS is before alg id?

Tags: certificates, embedded-system

From an **embedded systems** point of view it is inefficient to put the `alg ID` **after** `TBS` data in a certificate since an embedded system may not have a lot of hashing implementation and thus may not be able to verify the signature. Furthermore, it not only implies spending time to parse all these data but also keeping them in a buffer which results in a momentary waste of resources.

Am I missing something obvious? What is the security reason to put the `alg ID` field **after** the `TBS` field in a certificate?

Comment: For those who are wondering what TBS is: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1

Comment: Why not use the algorithm identifier inside the certificate itself (third field after the version and serial number)? The spec clearly states: `This field MUST contain the same algorithm identifier as the signature field in the sequence tbsCertificate`.

Comment: @Marc the `tbsCertificate` is still **before** the `signatureAlgorithm` [cf rfc5280#section-4.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.1)

Comment: We don't know the reason, that's just what the RFC says. But the TBSCertificate itself includes the signature algorithm, you can get this before the expensive parts of the certificate.

Comment: @Auzias are you hoping that you can change the order in the certificates you process? Or is this just theory? If the reason is purely arbitrary, does that affect your next steps?

Comment: No, no and no ;) As stated, in the question I am new to this and wonder if I am missing a security reason for this order. I obviously do not want nor hope to change it. Just understand the cause of this order that certainly is just an un-optimized and inefficient choice forcing embedded system to bufferize the begging of `TBS` until `AlgorithmIdentifier` is reached.